# How to filter notification for user by start date & end date. i have only time fields

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, fastapi

| id | user_id | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-08-21 04:29:25.992587 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-08-24 13:03:37.009491 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-08-24 13:03:37.009491 |
|  |  |  |

I want filter the **user activity** form this table by using start date and end date. i tried

```
SELECT id, user_id, "time" FROM public."tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-notification-my_activity" WHERE public."tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-notification-my_activity".user_id=2 AND  public."tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-notification-my_activity"."time"  BETWEEN \'2022-08-21T08:44:38.638510\' AND time ORDER BY "time" DESC;
```

But this is not properly filtering, requirements is frontend will give input and my api will be given filtered data by date and time

wrote this code

```
def get_user_activaity_filter(user_id,starting_date,ending_date, db: Session):
   
    data =  db.execute(f'SELECT id, user_id, "time" FROM public."tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-notification-my_activity" WHERE public."tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-notification-my_activity".user_id={user_id} AND  public."tbl_stu_usr-my_profile-notification-my_activity"."time"  BETWEEN \'2022-08-21T08:44:38.638510\' AND time ORDER BY "time" DESC;')
    get_user_notification = data.mappings().all()
    if not data:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,detail=f"There is nothing from database")

    return {'get_user_notification':get_user_notification}
```

**I get this data when a user login,** **so that this table has no end date**
This is not properly filtering. **How can i filter this so that in frontend it works properly**

Comment: `WHERE time BETWEEN <value1> AND <value2>`

Comment: i already tried this. i have no end date value, i have only start date

Comment: Than `time >= <value1>`

Comment: what type of sql are you using ?

Comment: postgresql. i have added the query what i used